# SQL Server Update from group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the column of a temp table from the count of a field from another table. I was trying to do this with the following query, but I get a syntax error.

How should I write this query?

Thanks!

```
UPDATE #ResultadosTest
SET PalletsReservados = COUNT(pe.paen_numero)
FROM #ResultadosTest RT, dba.spro_palletencab pe
WHERE pe.pate_tempor = RT.pate_tempor
  AND pe.expo_codigo = RT.expo_codigo
  AND pe.WeekLinId = RT.WeekLinId
  AND pe.plde_codigo = RT.plde_codigo
  AND pe.paen_estado = 1 
  AND ISNULL(pe.LoteCargaId, 0) <> 0 
  AND ISNULL(pe.PREMOPID, 0) <> 0 
GROUP BY 
    pe.pate_tempor, pe.expo_codigo, pe.WeekLinId, pe.plde_codigo
```

The error is:

> Line 10, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' (42000,156)

Comment: The first thing you should do is replace the implicit join with an explicit one.
The second thing is to show the complete error message, and preferably mark the row it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First group, then join

```
Update #ResultadosTest
SET PalletsReservados = pe.Cnt
FROM #ResultadosTest RT
JOIN (
    SELECT pate_tempor, expo_codigo, WeekLinId, plde_codigo, Count(pe.paen_numero) cnt
    FROM dba.spro_palletencab pe
    WHERE paen_estado=1 AND IsNull(LoteCargaId,0)<>0 AND IsNull(PREMOPID,0)<>0
    GROUP BY pate_tempor,expo_codigo,WeekLinId,plde_codigo
) pe ON pe.pate_tempor=RT.pate_tempor
AND pe.expo_codigo=RT.expo_codigo
AND pe.WeekLinId=RT.WeekLinId
AND pe.plde_codigo=RT.plde_codigo;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the JOIN(Select...) becames too slow. Finally I've created a temp table and then use a JOIN with the whole table. It's so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use an aggregate function at update statement. Instead you can you a derived table

```
Update #ResultadosTest
SET PalletsReservados = ppp.countpaen_numero
From (Select Count(pe.paen_numero) as countpaen_numero ,pe.pate_tempor,spro_palletencab,........
FROM #ResultadosTest RT,dba.spro_palletencab pe
Where pe.pate_tempor=RT.pate_tempor
AND pe.expo_codigo=RT.expo_codigo
AND pe.WeekLinId=RT.WeekLinId
AND pe.plde_codigo=RT.plde_codigo
AND pe.paen_estado=1 AND IsNull(pe.LoteCargaId,0)<>0 AND     IsNull(pe.PREMOPID,0)<>0 
GROUP BY pe.pate_tempor,pe.expo_codigo,pe.WeekLinId,pe.plde_codigo ) ppp
Where ppp.pate_tempor = Field..
```

Answer (score 0):

should work like:

```
    UPDATE RT
       SET PalletsReservados = pe.ctr
      FROM #ResultadosTest RT
INNER JOIN 
         (
            SELECT pate_tempor
                  ,expo_codigo
                  ,WeekLinId
                  ,plde_codigo
                  ,Count(pe.paen_numero) as ctr
              FROM dba.spro_palletencab 
             WHERE paen_estado            = 1
               AND ISNULL(LoteCargaId,0) <> 0
               AND ISNULL(PREMOPID,0)    <> 0 
             GROUP BY pe.pate_tempor
                     ,pe.expo_codigo
                     ,pe.WeekLinId
                     ,pe.plde_codigo               
         ) pe
        ON pe.pate_tempor   = RT.pate_tempor
       AND pe.expo_codigo   = RT.expo_codigo
       AND pe.WeekLinId     = RT.WeekLinId
       AND pe.plde_codigo   = RT.plde_codigo
```